# Async Callback API integration

Tags: java, asynchronous, microservices

**Async Callback API integration [Java]**

Hi All,
We are using few external system APIs, where we make a call to the external system using HTTP Rest Call and it responds back immediately with an acknowledgement (But not with actual response). After some time (~ 1 mins) external system responds back. In this scenario the system from my service to external service is completely Async. But I want to respond back to my client (service / system / SDK) in a synchronous manner. Meaning, the connection will remain open for that period of time between my system and my client system.

But the problem comes in the scenario of micro-service architecture. When my service (or system) is making call to the external service (or system) and get response back, the docker instance will be different from where I would have made a request. Ex: If I'm making a call to the external service from Node N1 and getting response back on Node N2 then it not been know about this response details. And also this making the system business logic tightly coupled with this Async system complexity.

Outward Request:
Client SDK -> My Service -> External Service

Inward Response:
Client SDK <- My Service <- External Service

Need your help in this scenario and problem statement immediately.

Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: You could configure your Load Balance to always route the calls to the same instance via session affinity. But this is not really the core issue here. The issue is your application architecture which is not designed to work properly in a Microservice landescape. 
Why is it, that you *must* connect to the instance? Can't you use a central Cache/DB/... to save the state for the response, so that all instances can access that?
What happens if this specific app crashes or gets removed? The you have the same problem. A microservice architecture is more than just building small scale services.

Comment: How does the external service respond back? Do you give it a webhook? The tie the response back to the right instance that way. Otherwise add a distributed cache and shove the details of all pending responses there - most caches support notifications - so you chuck something in the cache and then wait for ab update. Then this process or an entirely different one updates it. That’s a pretty complex solution - so the routing based solution is probably better.

Comment: @BoristheSpider How does the external service respond back? - through simple http call they are responding.

Comment: @Vaibhav - and how do they know the URL to call?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Thats a contract between our service and external service, that the request sent to them using HTTPs Rest calls and all the response for the same request id will be sent back to our system using HTTPs Rest call which will contain the same request id. Now when I receiving the response LB can redirect it to any of the docker instances, without knowing from where it got generated.

Comment: What I can see 2 way for solving this:

Answer (score 0):

What I can see 3 way for solving this:

1. **USING HAZELCAST CACHE**:  When the response will land (HTTPs call from the external service to my service) on my service that time it can land on any docker instance and it will just put it into the Hazelcast Cache. The Actual node from where this request was originated will just poll the Hazelcast with some duration (~ per second). And responds back once response found against the same request id or transaction id.
2. **USING THE LB ALGO - SOURCE IP HASH**: When the response will land (HTTPs call from the external service to my service) on my service LB it will find the hash of the source IP and finds the correct docker instance from where the request was originated.
3. **USING THE LB ALGO - TRANSACTION ID HASH**: When the response will land (HTTPs call from the external service to my service) on my service LB it will find the hash of the TRANSACTION ID present in the response headers and finds the correct docker instance from where the request was originated.

Comment: In solution 3, how will LB be able to determine the docker instance using just the TRANSACTION_ID? Will TRANSACTION_ID be cached too when the request goes out to the external system?
Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Akka Cluster Sharding + Akka Persistence is also a reasonable candidate for this sort of thing.